# how to set the width of daily bar chart in python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot the daily rainfall data of 5 years by the bar chart. when the width of bars is 1, they become lines without any width, while I changed the width of bars they overlapped each other like the image below. I want to have discrete bar charts with a good looking width. This my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
data=pd.read_excel('final.xlsx')
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
date = data['Date']
amount = data['Amount'] 
plt.bar (date, amount, color='gold', edgecolor='blue', align='center', width=5)
plt.ylabel('rainfall amount (mm)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide sample data / a [mre]? also, the indentation of you code seems to be off...

Comment: You would like to show 1500 bars with each bar clearly visible? If each bar would only be 1 mm you'd need a screen of 1.5 m wide. Maybe you could show accumulated data per month?

Comment: you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just to note, you can also pass a `Timedelta` to the `width` parameter; I find this helpful to be explicit about how many *units in x* (e.g. days here) the bars will take up.  Additionally for some time series the `int` widths are less intuitive:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fake data with minute frequency for an hour
dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2016 9:00:00', '01-01-2016 10:00:00', freq='1T')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dr)), index=dr)

#graph 1, using int width
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
plt.bar (df.index, df[0], color='gold', edgecolor='blue', align='center',
         width=1)

#graph 2, using Timedelta width
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
plt.bar (df.index, df[0], color='gold', edgecolor='blue', align='center',
         width=pd.Timedelta(minutes=1))
```

Graph 1:

[image]

Graph 2:

[image]

This was what came to mind when I saw your issue, but I think the real problem is the **amount of data points (as @JohanC pointed out)**.  Already when you plot 365 days, you can barely see the yellow anymore (and by 3 or 4 years its definitely gone):

[image]

You can also see in the above that different bars get rendered with different apparent widths, but that is just because there are too few pixels in the space provided to accurately show the bar fill and bar widths the same for each point.